# NSURLSessionTask: 'progress' property added in iOS11 appears to be useless

Tags: cocoa, ios11

New to `NSURLSessionTask` in iOS11 is a `progress` property:

> A representation of the overall task progress
>
> ```
> @property(readonly, strong) NSProgress *progress;
> ```

When queried while at 781334 of 1025886 bytes, the output is like this:

```
<NSProgress: 0x1c0324ec0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 1025886  
  <NSProgress: 0x1c0325140> : Parent: 0x1c0324ec0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 781334 of -1  
  <NSProgress: 0x1c03251e0> : Parent: 0x1c0324ec0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100
```

Note the `fractionCompleted` being 0.000 instead of 0.762.

When the data task finishes, the output of it's `progress` property looks like this:

```
<NSProgress: 0x1c4131440> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 5 of 1142597  
  <NSProgress: 0x1c4131580> : Parent: 0x1c4131440 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: -1 of -1
```

Note `Completed: 5 of 1142597`.

`NSURLSessionTask`'s progress reporting appears to be totally useless. So in order to report progress to a UI in iOS11, I still have to write the same boilerplate code as before. So what is the purpose of this new property?

Answer (score 0):

When reporting that bug with Apple, I created an example project, which is sitting here:
https://github.com/mickeyl/iOS-Bug-Example-Projects/tree/master/NSURLSessionTask-Progress-Broken

Here is an excerpt of a log created with the sample project above:

```
2018-06-15 12:02:17.641650+0200 NSURLSessionTask-Progress-Broken[74670:2636851] Progress = <NSProgress: 0x600000131800> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4588 / Completed: 5 of 100  
  <NSProgress: 0x600000131440> : Parent: 0x600000131800 / Fraction completed: 0.4303 / Completed: 462000019 of 1073741824
2018-06-15 12:02:17.641917+0200 NSURLSessionTask-Progress-Broken[74670:2636851] Progress = <NSProgress: 0x600000131800> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4588 / Completed: 5 of 100  
  <NSProgress: 0x600000131440> : Parent: 0x600000131800 / Fraction completed: 0.4303 / Completed: 462002915 of 1073741824
2018-06-15 12:02:17.642193+0200 NSURLSessionTask-Progress-Broken[74670:2636851] Progress = <NSProgress: 0x600000131800> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4588 / Completed: 5 of 100  
  <NSProgress: 0x600000131440> : Parent: 0x600000131800 / Fraction completed: 0.4303 / Completed: 462005811 of 1073741824
2018-06-15 12:02:17.642476+0200 NSURLSessionTask-Progress-Broken[74670:2636851] Progress = <NSProgress: 0x600000131800> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4588 / Completed: 5 of 100  
  <NSProgress: 0x600000131440> : Parent: 0x600000131800 / Fraction completed: 0.4303 / Completed: 462008707 of 1073741824
2018-06-15 12:02:17.642828+0200 NSURLSessionTask-Progress-Broken[74670:2636851] Progress = <NSProgress: 0x600000131800> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4588 / Completed: 5 of 100  
  <NSProgress: 0x600000131440> : Parent: 0x600000131800 / Fraction completed: 0.4303 / Completed: 462014499 of 1073741824
2018-06-15 12:02:17.643083+0200 NSURLSessionTask-Progress-Broken[74670:2636851] Progress = <NSProgress: 0x600000131800> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4588 / Completed: 5 of 100  
  <NSProgress: 0x600000131440> : Parent: 0x600000131800 / Fraction completed: 0.4303 / Completed: 462017395 of 1073741824
2018-06-15 12:02:17.643344+0200 NSURLSessionTask-Progress-Broken[74670:2636851] Progress = <NSProgress: 0x600000131800> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4588 / Completed: 5 of 100  
  <NSProgress: 0x600000131440> : Parent: 0x600000131800 / Fraction completed: 0.4303 / Completed: 462020291 of 1073741824
2018-06-15 12:02:17.643611+0200 NSURLSessionTask-Progress-Broken[74670:2636851] Progress = <NSProgress: 0x600000131800> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4588 / Completed: 5 of 100  
  <NSProgress: 0x600000131440> : Parent: 0x600000131800 / Fraction completed: 0.4303 / Completed: 462023187 of 1073741824
2018-06-15 12:02:17.643878+0200 NSURLSessionTask-Progress-Broken[74670:2636851] Progress = <NSProgress: 0x600000131800> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4588 / Completed: 5 of 100  
  <NSProgress: 0x600000131440> : Parent: 0x600000131800 / Fraction completed: 0.4303 / Completed: 462026083 of 1073741824

[...]

2018-06-15 12:03:29.216655+0200 NSURLSessionTask-Progress-Broken[74670:2636247] Progress = <NSProgress: 0x600000131800> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 5 of 100  
  <NSProgress: 0x600000131440> : Parent: 0x600000131800 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 1073727891 of 1073741824
2018-06-15 12:03:29.217201+0200 NSURLSessionTask-Progress-Broken[74670:2636854] Progress = <NSProgress: 0x600000131800> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 5 of 100  
  <NSProgress: 0x600000131440> : Parent: 0x600000131800 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 1073730787 of 1073741824
2018-06-15 12:03:29.217407+0200 NSURLSessionTask-Progress-Broken[74670:2636854] Progress = <NSProgress: 0x600000131800> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 5 of 100  
  <NSProgress: 0x600000131440> : Parent: 0x600000131800 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 1073733683 of 1073741824
2018-06-15 12:03:29.217889+0200 NSURLSessionTask-Progress-Broken[74670:2637014] Progress = <NSProgress: 0x600000131800> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 5 of 100  
  <NSProgress: 0x600000131440> : Parent: 0x600000131800 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 1073739475 of 1073741824
2018-06-15 12:03:29.218147+0200 NSURLSessionTask-Progress-Broken[74670:2637014] Progress = <NSProgress: 0x600000131800> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 100 of 100
```

Here we can observe that – for some reason – for one `NSURLSessionTask` there is a parent and a child `NSProgress` created. While the child progress contains the proper information, the parent process seems to stick with 5 / 100 units for most of the time. At least it gets the `fractionCompleted` somewhat right.

So: When sticking to the child `NSProgress` the `progress` property is somewhat useful.

Unfortunately I need to support iOS all the way down to 9, which is why I will have to create my own substitute anyways.